# Odd number list for hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get a rails website up and running from github, and I'm encountering these errors:

```
WARNING: 'task :t, arg, :needs => [deps]' is deprecated.  Please use 'task :t, [args] => [deps]' instead.
    at /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sunspot_rails-1.2.1/lib/sunspot/rails/tasks.rb:41 rake aborted! /Users/robertgrzesik/Documents/RubyOnRails/IndieOption/app/helpers/advertisements_helper.rb:15: odd number list for Hash
          user_id: current_user.id,
                  ^ /Users/robertgrzesik/Documents/RubyOnRails/IndieOption/app/helpers/advertisements_helper.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
          user_id: current_user.id,
                  ^ /Users/robertgrzesik/Documents/RubyOnRails/IndieOption/app/helpers/advertisements_helper.rb:16: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
          page: request.url
               ^ /Users/robertgrzesik/Documents/RubyOnRails/IndieOption/app/helpers/advertisements_helper.rb:17: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting kEND
        })
         ^ /Users/robertgrzesik/Documents/RubyOnRails/IndieOption/app/helpers/advertisements_helper.rb:20: odd number list for Hash
          page: request.url
               ^ /Users/robertgrzesik/Documents/RubyOnRails/IndieOption/app/helpers/advertisements_helper.rb:20: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
          page: request.url
               ^ /Users/robertgrzesik/Documents/RubyOnRails/IndieOption/app/helpers/advertisements_helper.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting kEND
        })
         ^
```

for this code:

```
if ad
  if current_user
    ad.impressions.create({
      user_id: current_user.id,
      page: request.url
    })
  else
    ad.impressions.create({
      page: request.url
    })
  end
  link_to external_redirect_advertisement_url(ad) do
    image_tag ad.image.url(format)
  end
else
  nil
end
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're trying to use 1.9 hash syntax (`key: value`) with a 1.8 Ruby (`:key => value`).

Comment: This helped me, my style guide uses >= 1.9 hadn't mentioned this and my system is using 1.8. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Dave, I'm on ruby -v 1.8.7, Rails 3. I have syntax like such:

dic = { :key => ["A", "B", "C", "D"] }

But I'm still getting the same error. Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: @djbhindi You can't get an error regarding hash syntax from that line in either Ruby 1.8 or later versions. If suggest asking a new question with the precise error and the code that's causing it.

Answer (score 6):

What version of Ruby are you running? The hashes look correct at first glance, but the `foo: 'bar'` hash syntax is 1.9+ only. If you're using Ruby 1.8.x you'll need up upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, performing side-effects (record creation) within a helper is probably one of the last things you should do. Anyway, a refactor proposal (I don't see the need to check `current_user`, no need for a `else nil`, Ruby does that by default):

```
if ad
  ad.impressions.create(:user => current_user, :page => request.url)
  link_to external_redirect_advertisement_url(ad) do
    image_tag(ad.image.url(format))
  end
end
```